# Mongo db find string in a list with .net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have several records in Posts collection which has Tags field as

```
"Tags" : [ "Xyr,zau,iRS" ]
```

and I want to find all posts containing tag I send to a function. What is the right way to do it?

Some of the things I have tried and coun't retrieve any data are,

tag as string parametre

```
var builder = Builders<Post>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("Tags", tag);

var filter = new BsonDocument("Tags", new BsonDocument("$eq", tag));

var filter = new BsonDocument("Tags", new BsonDocument("$in", tag)); // That one somehow generated an error

var filter= new BsonDocument("Tags", tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Tags` filed is like this:

```
"Tags" : [ "Xyr", "zau", "iRS" ]
```

Then you can use "$in" query in MongoDB driver 2.0 like this:

 [API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_In__1.htm)

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.In("Tags", new string[] { tag });
```

Comment: it seems you are right, it should be the way you have shown but it is not at the moment. Better fix that somehow and then try find().

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake on Tags. Inserting Tags property in the very first place to mongodb, sorted out all my find issues.

Comment: @Lapsens Glad to hear that.